# Setting directory and loading data from inside a function R

Tags: r

I'm trying to use start() function in order to set directory and load files depending on which computer I am using. Unfortunately the below code does not work, because after executing start("M") the directory does not change and the data objects are not present in the environment. Everything works if I just execute the lines of code separately (without putting it in a function. Why is that? How to modify it so that it works as intended? Thank you for help.

```
setwdMacbook = function(){
  setwd("~/Dropbox/Rfiles/")
}
setwdWindows = function(){
  setwd("C:/Users/user1/Dropbox/Rfiles")
}
loadDataMacbook = function(){
  load("~/Dropbox/Rfiles/allData1.Rda")
  load("~/Dropbox/Rfiles/aData1.Rda")
  load("~/Dropbox/Rfiles/usrData1.Rda")
}
loadDataWindows = function(){
  load("C:/Users/user1/Dropbox//Rfiles/allData1.Rda")
  load("C:/Users/user1/Dropbox//Rfiles/aData1.Rda")
  load("C:/Users/user1/Dropbox//Rfiles/usrData1.Rda")
}

start = function(whichComputer="M"){
  if(all.equal(whichComputer, "M")){
    setwdMacbook()
    loadDataMacbook()
    print("setwd and load data on personal Macbook")
  }else if(all.equal(whichComputer, "W")){
    setwdWindows()
    loadDataWindows()
    print("setwd and load data on Windows computer at the office")
  }else{
    print("Insert W for Windows computer at the office and M for personal Macbook computer.")
  }
}

start("M")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `load` to specify the `envir` param:

```
load(..., envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

Otherwise you're just loading into the environment of the `start` call evaluation.  `setwd` should work; not sure why it isn't working for you.

Comment: Thanks!, this is what I needed to know! And yes, stewed works now that I checked it with getwd(), just in RStudio it doesn't change the directory shown in the files window, so I thought it didn't work either. Thanks!